# jQuery hover with setTimeout (opposite to hoverIntent)

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout, hoverintent

I have a set of images that for each one I would like to rollover and flicker to a different image for half a second or so, then revert back to the original image, even if the mouse is still over the image (ie there's no mouseout)

setTimeout was suggested but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

http://thepool.ie/rollover/

There's an example of the page....I'd just like the image that appears on rollover to appear then disappear again quickly.

I've scoured the web for examples and can't find anything...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Andrew

Edit:

This is the code I'm currently using for hover images

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$(function() {
    $('.rollover').hover(function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    }, function() {
        var currentImg = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('hover'));
        $(this).attr('hover', currentImg);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: do i understand you right? The mouse enters the image, the images changes for a few seconds and is getting back to the previous image again. Nothing happens when the mouse moves out of the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` is easy. It takes a function as the first argument  — just like many jQuery methods — and the time in milliseconds as the second.

I started with your code and refactored it a bit. Originally, there would have been the potential for a race condition if the user mouses over, away from, and then back over the image before the timer fires. Now, the logic for switching to the alternate image and back to the original is separate. The mouseover handler also short-circuits if the images are already swapped out. I also cache the jQuery object returned by `$(this)`, for a slight speed improvement (caching jQuery objects is good practice).

I changed the `hover` attribute to `data-hover` (the HTML5 spec lets you use custom attributes but requires that they start with `data-`) and checked for its presense in the mouseover selector.

Finally, I removed the extra `ready` wrapper (`$(document).ready(function(){…})` and `$(function(){…}` are the same, no need to have both of them).

```
$(function() {
    $('.rollover[data-hover]').mouseover(function() {
        var $this = $(this), originalImage = $this.attr('src');
        if ($this.data('imagesSwapped')) {
            return;
        }
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('data-hover')).data('imagesSwapped', true);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.attr('src', originalImage).removeData('imagesSwapped');
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

The code has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks you so much Sidnicious. That works perfectly, you were incredibly helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some clear examples:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/

But I would personally advice you to use the Timers plugin, which is more friendly to use:
http://jquery.offput.ca/every/

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$('#myid').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    setTimeout(function() { $('#myid').removeClass('hovered'); }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Scaryzet, 

I'm quite a beginner...this is the code I'm currently using

http://thepool.ie/rollover.js

If you could show me where to add the code you're suggesting it'd be excellent. 

Thanks so much.
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

There is better way that setTimeOut

you can use `$('.rollover').mouseenter(function() {` instead of `$('.rollover').hover(function() {`  http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/